# When do you have to require a module in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Say you have

```
module MyFirstModule
  def say_hello
    puts "Hello"
  end
end
```

and

```
class ModuleTester
  include MyFirstModule
end
```

Do you need a `require MyFirstModule` statement above the class definition? Do you ever need to require the module? When, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never `require` modules, you `require` files.

In the above example, if the two fragments that you posted were in different files, e.g. `my_first_module.rb` and `module_tester.rb`, then you would have to do

```
require "my_first_module"
```

before you could reference `MyFirstModule`.

(Obviously, if they were in the same file, no `require` statement would be necessary, and would not make sense anyway, as there would be no file to `require`.)

What `require` does is to look for the given Ruby file in the *library path*, and then load the Ruby file, just as if you had executed it.  The file will be loaded at most once during the runtime of your program (which is the difference to the `load` command, which is otherwise very similar to `require`).

In the above example, before you can use `MyFirstModule`, you'll have to `require` the file that defines it.

Be aware that there is an auto loading mechanism which can `require` files automatically for you.  Also, Rails does `require` most classes automatically.  So don't be confused that in some cases a `require` statement does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: How does that auto loading mechanism work? And how do you know what classes in Rails are required automatically?

Comment: Autoload works by using something like `autoload :MyFirstModule 'libs/my_first_module'` in your code, which will then run a `require 'libs/my_first_module'` automatically the first time `MyFirstModule` is used.  Rails has a more sophisticated approach to this, so you can edit classes (e.g. models) that you use, click reload in the browser, and have the new version load.  It does this by manually unloading the files that have already been required.  Rails does this for all classes it knows about by convention (models, controllers, stuff in the `lib/` folder etc.)

Comment: Technically it does not unload the *files*, but it makes the runtime forget about the classes that have changed, so the autoload will re-`require` the respective files. It's kind of a hack, and can lead to very nasty problems down the road (if you don't know about it happening).

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the great explanations! Let me ask you another question: how did you get to have such a good understanding of all this stuff? I took a few Java classes in college, tried a few Rails tutorials, and now I'm learning Ruby with The Well Grounded Rubyist. Do you have a strong CS background? What did you do to understand all of this Ruby and Rails?

Comment: I have a strong CS background and I've been working with Ruby on Rails for several years.  You will run into all these issues sooner or later, and learn from it.  There are a great many people who are a lot more knowledgeable than I am.  Ruby is a powerful language and Rails is very complex.  It doesn't come easy.  Always remeber that Ruby is NOT the same as Rails.

Comment: So did you just understand everything after reading the documentation?

Comment: The Rails documentation is not very good.  You need to piece your knowledge together.  Go have a look at Railscasts, and buy some books.  The Pragmatic Bookshelf is a good publisher for Ruby and Rails books.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice! I subscribed to RailsCasts and watched a bunch and I read Agile Web Dev with Rails 4. I'm getting better, but still probably need a few months of practice before I'm a "useful" programmer.

Comment: Yeah, don't worry about it, it will happen.  By the way the class loader thing I specifically know about because we ran into a nasty bug at work which was related to it.  Otherwise I wouldn't know about it. With experience and practice comes knowledge.  And I google a lot, too, of course (usually ending up at this very site ;-).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to require.  'Include' will expose the method say_hello to your class as you desire.  'Require' is used to pull in all the code from another file.  So if you had defined MyFirstModule in another file, you would require that file so that you could then include the module in your class.

Comment: This answer is misleading.  He did not say that the two fragments he posted are in the same file.